# What does cap product actually mean?

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, geometric-topology

I have read the Wikipedia definition of cap product. Here is the Wikipedia definition that I know. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cap_product

What I understand: For a good space, for example, an orientable closed $n$ manifold using the Poincare Duality and definition of cup product, I can convince myself that there should be such a map, but I don't understand what this bilinear map actually mean. Can anyone please clarify the definition? I just want to know what motivates us to define cap product, and what actually it means.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you want to know what a bilinear map is?

Comment: What would it "actually" mean that isn't in the definition?

Comment: I just see this bilinear map can take a bigger chain, and return a smaller chain.

Comment: @anomaly There are plenty of obfuscating definitions that have illuminating geometric interpretations. I would say that geometry is what the definition could “actually” mean.

Comment: Yes, I meant the geometric interpretation.

Comment: @MMM I’m not comfortable enough with this to write a cohesive answer, but there’s a sense in which the cap product describes a geometric intersection (using Poincaré duality). You may appreciate [this discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/q/190945/95243) over at MO.

Comment: Thank you very much. It helps a lot.

Comment: It basically means integration. 
If you have a manifold than cap product can be interpreted in terms of deRham cohomology. Cohomological classes are represented by differential forms and you integrate these forms along certain cycles on a manifold.

This approach could be extended to a general situation using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_homotopy_theory

Comment: Thank you so much. I will read this page. Please note that I have never learned deRham cohomology. Thanks again.